# Including Processing.js sketch in Wordpress website only shows empty canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, processing.js

I'm trying to include a Processing.js game in a Wordpress website. I'm getting the sketch from Rawgit using an Ajax call, but when I preview the page, it just shows an empty canvas.

Here's a sample version of my code (right now it's being used to load a sketch that draws a red ellipse):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/Larpee/The-Khan-Quiz/master/style.css' type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">Page Name</div>
        <div id="game-window"><h5 id="game-title">Game name</h5>
        <canvas id="game"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$.get("https://rawgit.com/Larpee/The-Khan-Quiz/master/test.txt", function (game) {
    var sketchProc = function (processingInstance) {
        with (processingInstance) {
            size(400, 400);
            frameRate(30);
            eval(game);
        }
    };

    var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
});

</script>
</html>
```

You can try the game and look at its code using this link: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/the-khan-quiz/6282341959729152

Why is this not working?

Comment: do you get any responses in the console?

Comment: @Sam0 Yes, it shows 3 errors: The first two are "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". The third one says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: not sure I can help. with the first two errors there should be a line number associated (if you're using chrome at least) you should be able to click on this and have it indicate where the issue is. also, when you mentioned previewing the page I assume you mean running this as a freestanding script outside of wp?

Comment: Why are you fetching the JavaScript via ajax instead of simply including it in a `script` tag?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the actual code you're trying to run? Preferably in the form of a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman is right on both counts, also both of your `https://rawgit.com/username/gameName/master/...` resources are 404 missing, which might be the root cause of your problem. Please address these and update the question

Comment: @Sam0 No, when I said previewing the page, I meant previewing it with Wordpress. When I try opening the page with the same code outside of wp, everything works fine

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'm fetching it via an Ajax call because I don't just want to run it, I want to load it and then execute it inside sketchProc. I'm also using Ajax because I'm planning to add a "Play" button, and show the game in response to that button being clicked. I added a link to the game in the question, but I'm quite sure the problem is not there

Comment: Okay, in this case please indicate how you are trying  previewing through wordpress? Are you trying to do this through a post or woven into a theme? css and js scripts will need to be called via the php `scripts.php` or `functions.php` typically otherwise this causes the same problems you've been having.

Comment: @Larpee I still don't understand why you can't load the sketch via a plain old `script` tag and still do all the things you're talking about.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can actually run. This includes a basic `index.html` file that loads your script via ajax, as well as a basic sketch being loaded. Right now we're getting an incomplete picture. We also don't need to see your entire sketch, just a basic example that exhibits the problem. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman How would I do the things I said before with a plain script tag? I'm new to web development, so I'm learning things on the fly. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: @Sam0 I'm actually creating a new page, and adding the HTML file I included in the question there. When you create a new page, wp lets you preview it. Should I add the script in functions.php even if I only want to use it in that one page?

Comment: @KevinWorkman As for your last comment, I changed to code in the question. It now includes a simple sketch that just draws a red ellipse, is that what you meant for me to do?

Comment: Regarding your `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".`'s please state the line number locations of these errors indicated by the console. consider also this site: http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2013/04/embedding-js-script-tags-in-wordpress-posts.html

Comment: @Sam0 These are the errors: https://github.com/Larpee/The-Khan-Quiz/blob/master/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo.jpg?raw=true

Comment: @Sam0 I tried the solution suggested in the link you provided and it worked. I can't thank you enough for your time and attention, I thought I was never going to fix it. Again, thank you very much!